# Update Existing .XLSX or .CSV File in C# - Editing Spreadsheet Cells without having to open Excel Application

Tags: c#, excel

There are some answers on how to *update* excel spread sheets using `c#`. However all of these answers are several years old, and most require opening in excel. I am looking for a more recent solution; where I  make the edits, and do this *without using excel*

What I'm looking to do is *update* an existing `.xlsx` file and *save* that file into memory then email that stream.

If you have pointers on how to save the file into memory, that would be helpful.
But the real solution that I am looking for is updating an existing `.xlsx` file problematically using `c#`, not having to open excel. I don't need to add any *columns* or *workbooks* all I need to do is simply update cells.

Comment: Did you look at the MSDN documentation? [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342218.aspx)

Comment: Do you have excel installed on the pc or is it serverbased, if serverbased have a look at openxml https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 it is pretty steep learning curve, but there are examples and frameworks building on top of it.

Comment: @dennis_ler It is server based. I am doing this inside a C# MVC web application. The front end gets a user's response, I need to update an existing excel file using the model that is posted back from the front-end. Put the updated excel in memory and email it. I know that using a database to store the responses then creating a new excel based on that would be idea. But based on requirements and security issue by storing this information on the server (for legal reasons we can't store this information on our servers). I don't see another way of doing this.

Comment: @J.McCabe I have looked at the MSDN documentation, however this requires opening excel to make the changes. Are there any other methods where this isn't required? Or are there any api's that you would recommend?

Comment: Would the solution be much easier if the file was .csv instead of .xlsx?

Comment: Yes with CSV, you can indeed change, and write that file stream from memory directly to an attachment for SmtpClient

Comment: @dgorti I have the option of using csv, that will save me alot of headache. Do you have any example code or a link that i could reference?

Comment: Example code for changing CSV or attaching files to smtp client?

Comment: @dgorti Both if you have it. If not either.

Comment: If you're using visual studio, you can use nuget to add EPPLUS to your application and use c#. It's free also, worth a look.

Comment: @nocturns2 EPPLUS is exaclty what i was looking for. Here is the to the website [link](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) . It was easy work with, and has a lot of potential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a specific question, but perhaps there is value in addressing a few points here.

1. **Updating XLSX file:** Since this is not a simple file, you can't just open using a file open operation and edit a single file. An XLSX is a complex document, saved in XML or binary or other formats. So you need an API. You can use the built in Excel Automation objects on windows or other APIs for various platforms and languages.
2. **Do I need to Open the file and launch Excel?**: No you don't have to. But If you use Excel.Application or other APIs, the Excel program is launched. Whether it is visibile or not can be controlled, but Excel.exe is the software that gets the job done when you use Excel Automation Objects. Otehr APIS like closedXml or other Excel libraries may be working at the XML level, so they don't actually open excel.exe and can get the job done.
3. **Saving in memory and directly sending via email**: This is a tough one. I don't think it is possible. Most of the libraries that I mentioned about, can be working on one or more of the underlying compound document parts, so once again, because it is not a simple file, you can't edit in memory and attach.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions regarding xml api's where i can make edits without having to open excel?

Comment: Since you tagged the question with C#, i can see that a possible candidate is the closedxml library. I have not used it, so I can;t speak to its functionality